# How to create integer password EditText programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I need to create `EditText` field programmatically. But it must be a `inputType` of `int` and also it has to be a `password` field.How can I achieve this? I tried these but not working.

- `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);`
- `editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));`
- `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);`

Comment: please dont just down-vote and leave.Tell what is wrong with this question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in what way is it not working? Does it show at all? Can you enter numbers into it?

Comment: it shows.But it does not create a *int password* field.I want it to be get only int and it does not show what i type(passoword)

Comment: I think you mean programmatically. The first try will not work, because the two input types that you are trying to combine are mutually exclusive. The second one might work if you reverse the order of the two statements.

Comment: @sampathpremarathna just right edittext xml or whatever runtime properties digit=0123456789 and inputtype=password its working for me

Comment: but the requirement still there :(.@altaf

Answer (score 14):

Give this a try:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```